# Different Node versions in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos

Is it possible to run different Node versions in OS X El Capitan with Homebrew?

Comment: Yes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751222/multiple-side-by-side-versions-with-homebrew) on StackOverflow.

Comment: @uint128_t Should make that an answer, as it seems to be complete enough to answer the question.

Comment: @JMY1000 Fair enough, done :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When node updates a package, it doesn't remove the old version. You can also install old versions of a package using `brew versions`, but you will probably need to install the `boneyard` tap in order to be able to do this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula/4158763#4158763) and [here](http://effectif.com/mac-os-x/installing-specific-version-of-homebrew-formula).

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751222/multiple-side-by-side-versions-with-homebrew) answer:
Use `ls $(brew --cellar)` to determine what you have installed, and `brew ls -v` to see installed packages and versions. You can then call the installed binaries directly (or make your own aliases to them).